# Linker Errors compiling Thrift on Mac OS 10.9.3 with XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, homebrew, osx-mavericks, thrift

Trying to compile the tutorial cpp files on http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/cpp.

I get a couple of these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "shared::SharedServiceProcessor::process_getStruct(int,apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol*, void*)", referenced from:
```

I installed boost and thrift using homebrew with updated brew files. Some sources suggested compiling boost and thrift with gcc4.8 and the libstdc++ files but other libraries I'm using need libc++ and c++11 support.

Also Looking into the brew file from thrift:

```
 ENV.cxx11 if MacOS.version >= :mavericks && ENV.compiler == :clang
```

I also tried setting Xcode Architecture to *32-bit Intel i386* still no luck

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may want to ask the question on the mailing list.

Comment: How are you compiling the files?
I was able to compile by following instructions on : http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC++